# How to reference a text file in python

Tags: python, authentication, text

I'm attempting to make a python program that simulates a login. The goal for the program is to write then read a text file to see if the username(User_name) and password(password) match then log you in!. **My problem is its not reading the file and when it writes its on a single line** for example the output to my text file  is usernameusernameusername, i'm unsure if that messes up the program when reading if the username already exists.

```
 info = open("user_info.txt", "a+")
user_status = input("Are you a new user (Y)es or (N)o")
if user_status.lower() == ("y"):
    print("Welcome To Login Master 1000")
    user_name = input("Type in user name")
    if str(user_name) in info.readlines():
        print("That Name Is Taken")
    info.write(user_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple issues here. First, you cannot read the file because you're opening it with `a+` and so you read from the last line, so instead you have to add:

```
info.seek(0)
```

I'd also suggest adding a `,` to ensure the names don't mix:

```
info.write(f"{user_name},")
```

Lastly, I'd suggest opening the file with a `with` statement so you don't accidentily leave it open:

```
with open("user_info.txt", "a+") as info:
```

Putting it all together:

```
with open("user_info.txt", "a+") as info:
    info.seek(0)
    user_status = input("Are you a new user (Y)es or (N)o")
    if user_status.lower() == ("y"):
        print("Welcome To Login Master 1000")
        user_name = input("Type in user name")
        if str(user_name) in info.read().split(','):
            print("That Name Is Taken")
        info.write(f"{user_name},")
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out and write a great answer with steps!

Answer (score 0):

Great start to your program.  Couple things here... when you are manually opening files for modification, you have to manually close the file at the end of your program with `info.close()`.

The decision for how to store your data in a file has been changed since the beginning of computers.  For simplicity and learning sake, you may just want to store your usernames and passwords in a comma separated file, `.csv` Or space separated file.  This will allow you to read a line and then split the line into their individual strings for testing.

When writing to file I believe you can append strings with the `+` operator.  So to create a space separated file you could `info.write(user_name+“,”+”password”+”\n”)`. Now you have an comma to split off of and only one user and password saved in your file per line.

Your file may be reading already.  To see if the file is being read, before the if statement try `print(“Current line is -> “,info.readline())` as readline will read only one line.

If the file is not being read or there is no content in that print or you get an error, then it could be the permission on your file or its a simple option in your `a+` option needs to be changed.

Next, the keyword `in` is not checking the content as you intend although this is a good idea.
`in` is better used to iterate every line of the file `for line in info:`
`Print(info.readline())`
The advantage to this method is you can split each line username and password into a list with split. So ->

```
For line in info:
    Print(line)
    Tokens = line.split(“,”) # if comma separated
    If user_name == tokens[0]:
        #Matched input username with file content
```

Now when you print tokens you will have a comma separated list looking like `[“Username”,”password”]` and then you can access `”Username”` with `Tokens[0]` and you can access `”password”` with `Tokens[1]` because list indexing starts with 0.

Comment: Thanks, this a a more organized way to sort my info on users, I really like it! Thanks for taking the time to help me out. This is my first post, but I can already see the members on here will be a big help!